# Spring: How to test a filter which requires Spring Security

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-security

I've written a filter which operates on the Principal of a HTTP request.  So in my application I've made sure that it runs after the Spring Security filters.  It works fine.

However, I'm having trouble testing it.  I read [this](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/23/preview-spring-security-test-web-security) and followed the steps to create this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

    private MockMvc mvc;
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain, new MyFilter())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void anonymousCallsNotLogged() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(post("/").with(anonymous()));
    }

    public static class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {
        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableWebMvc
    static class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    }
}
```

When I debug it, I do not see my filter fire, but I do see the Spring Security filters working.

However when I switch their order:

```
.addFilters(new MyFilter(), springSecurityFilterChain)
```

I see both fire.  Unfortunately in the wrong order!  It looks like the Spring Security stuff isn't call the rest of the filter chain.

My question is - why is this happening and what can I do about it!?

Answer (score 0):

**Q)** Why wasn't the HTTP request making it past Spring Security?

**A)** Because it was hitting the CSRF filter

I needed to either:

**Enable CSRF on the request:**

```
mvc.perform(post("/").with(csrf()));
```

or

**Disable CSRF in the config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvc
static class Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have that `Config extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which basically mess with any `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you have in the project. Remove the `extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to fix it.